# A/B split of a dataset in Python with specific conditions

Tags: python, machine-learning

My objective is to divide a dataset of 9 columns into two different stratified datasets. Seven columns must be stratified and the other two must be split in a specific way.

I checked for A/B splitting libraries but I did not find one, so I just used `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`, setting the `test_size=0.5` in order to have both datasets with the same length. As `y`, I passed the columns that must be stratified.

`X`contains the data does not need to be split in a stratified way. `y` contains the data that needs to be stratified.

`aux, aux1, ya, yb = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.5)`

Then, I merge `aux`and `ya` to obtain one split and `aux1` and `yb` to obtain the other one.

`a = pd.merge(aux, ya, left_index=True, right_index=True)
b = pd.merge(aux1, yb, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

It worked, but two of the stratified columns are `caseID` and  `personID`. There can be several rows with the same caseID, as well as several rows with the same personID.

I cannot allow a caseID to be present in both splits, neither I can allow a personID to be present in both. So I need to set a constraint in a way that a person must always be in the same split; and the same for a case, a caseID cannot be in both splits.

For example, if I have three rows with the following values:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               CaseID              |  PersonID  |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| 1                                 |     2      |
| 1                                 |     3      |
| 2                                 |     5      |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

The first two must be in the same split since they have the same CaseID.

Is there any library/function that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to collect the case+person mappings and just split those into discrete piles, then collect all the other columns for each person and case?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your answer. You mean unifying those with the same CaseID or personID under one row?
If not, could you maybe explain with an example?
Thanks!

Comment: To simplify, let's just divide your persons into two piles. Now your A test set is all the samples which contains persons from pile A, and your B test set is all the rest, which will contain all the persons from pile B.  Having both persons and cases will complicate matters -- in the worst case you have a long transitive chain where person 1 occurs in case *alpha* which also involves person 2 which also is affected by case *beta* which also involves person 3, etc.

Comment: Also, on Stack Overflow, comments are not answers. If I had an actual answer I would use the big friendly answer box below.

Comment: But how do I know that the values related to the people from A are similar to those regarding the people from B. As I said, I want those other columns split in a stratified way.

I am starting to consider that the only option might be to iterate over the dataframe, and if the row I am at contains a person or case that is already in a split, send that row to that split. Otherwise, check how the values of the other columns are being split, and based on that, send that row to the best split (so that they are stratified at the end).

Comment: Of course, no such guarantees can be made in the general case. You have to know your data or provide a lot more details to let someone figure out how to ensure that the division is balanced. Even then, you seem to be introducing a bias. What if the values in the two sets are genuinely and necessarily different? In the trivial case, what if you only have two persons in your data?

Answer (score 0):

For this method you need to use the technique commonly referred to as split-apply-combine. For this we would be using Groupbys.

Your first task would be to split the data into relevant groups.

```
df_by_CaseID = df.groupby('CaseID')
```

After this you will apply your splits, you will have to put in some work here as you would be shuffling the groupby objects and not dataframe.  [Read here for more on groupby.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

And then you can combine each groupby item using the `pd.dataframe`.

After getting this, do remember to shuffle this data as it would be grouped by caseID and that can have consequences on your model, If you have and doubts, comment below. also [checkout this,](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-split-apply-combine-groupby) for an overview explanation.